# jQuery each function not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am generating circular counters for polls where I draw counter for each answer.

I am using this "plugin": http://blakek.us/labs/jquery/css3-pie-graph-timer/

### Problem:

It is not getting text value from `<div>` and not drawing Counter for each div.

*Note: For one div is working good*

### Example:

http://jsbin.com/AHUkoBA/3/edit

http://jsfiddle.net/mgcq9/

### HTML:

```
<div class="pollAnswerBar">15</div>
<div class="pollAnswerBar">50</div>
<div class="pollAnswerBar">75</div>
```

### JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    function drawCounter(percent) {
        jQuery('div.pollAnswerBar').html('<div class="percent"></div><div id="slice"' + (percent > 50 ? ' class="gt50"' : '') + '><div class="pie"></div>' + (percent > 50 ? '<div class="pie fill"></div>' : '') + '</div>');
        var deg = 360 / 100 * percent;
        jQuery('#slice .pie').css({
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',
            'transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)'
        });
        jQuery('.percent').html(Math.round(percent) + '%');
    }

    jQuery('.pollAnswerBar').each(function() {
        var percent = jQuery(this).text();
        console.log(percent);
        drawCounter(percent);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fKPb6/

You were modifying all elements rather than specifying each one individually.

Here is working code.

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    function drawCounter(percent, element) {
        jQuery(element).html('<div class="percent"></div><div id="slice"' + (percent > 50 ? ' class="gt50"' : '') + '><div class="pie"></div>' + (percent > 50 ? '<div class="pie fill"></div>' : '') + '</div>');
        var deg = 360 * (percent / 100);
        jQuery('#slice .pie', element).css({
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',
                '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',
                'transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)'
        });
        jQuery('.percent', element).html(Math.round(percent) + '%');
    }

    jQuery('.pollAnswerBar').each(function (index, element) {
        var percent = jQuery(element).text();
        console.log(percent);
        drawCounter(percent, element);
    });

});
```

By limiting the selection to the scope of the individual element e.g. `jQuery('.percent', element)` you are targeting the correct element rather than all `.percent` elements.

Comment: That's it. My problem was that I forgot **scope each element** :)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the event handler like this:

```
// Pass the event handler here
jQuery('.pollAnswerBar').each(drawCounter);
```

and call the function like:

```
// Declare the event handler with params passed from .each()
function drawCounter(i, elm) {
    var percent = $(elm).text();
    jQuery(elm).html('<div class="percent"></div><div id="slice"' + (percent > 50 ? ' class="gt50"' : '') + '><div class="pie"></div>' + (percent > 50 ? '<div class="pie fill"></div>' : '') + '</div>');
    var deg = 360 * (percent / 100);
    jQuery('#slice .pie', elm).css({
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',
            'transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)'
    });
    jQuery('.percent', elm).html(Math.round(percent) + '%');
}
```

Demo: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mgcq9/5/)

---

Or only using the `this` keyword without any parameters being passed like:

```
// Pass the event handler here
jQuery('.pollAnswerBar').each(drawCounter);

// Declare the event handler using `this`
function drawCounter() {
    var percent = $(this).text();
    jQuery(this).html('<div class="percent"></div><div id="slice"' + (percent > 50 ? ' class="gt50"' : '') + '><div class="pie"></div>' + (percent > 50 ? '<div class="pie fill"></div>' : '') + '</div>');
    var deg = 360 * (percent / 100);
    jQuery('#slice .pie', this).css({
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',
            'transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)'
    });
    jQuery('.percent', this).html(Math.round(percent) + '%');
}
```

Demo: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mgcq9/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify each() function here Try this:

```
function myfun(){
        var percent = jQuery(this).text();
        console.log(percent);
        drawCounter(percent);
    });
jQuery('.pollAnswerBar').myfun();
```